# can't resolve symbole 'set.OnClickListener' Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Hi everybody i am started my first  app on android studio and iam getting this error in "can't resolve symbole 'set.OnClickListener'" as shown in image below 
please i made many searches in google to solve it but nothing found.
So please somebody help.
thanks.

```
package com.example.omar.app1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import static android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

b.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class)); }

});
```

}

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WrLkf.jpg

Comment: thanks for everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all the code relating to your Button inside `onCreate()` (after `setContentView()`, before the closing `}`).

Comment: Thanks Man You Saved me

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as accepted so other answerers know this problem has been resolved 

Answer (score 1):

**My example is:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this documentation will help you [Button Class](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Button.html) and  [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

All the codes related to button must be within the onCreate() method after the line : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

These lines :

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

b.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class)); }

});
```

must be written within onCreate method after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Answer (score 0):

The error is Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

you declare your button and initialize it in compile time with

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and of course before, you crete the view is impossibile to find id without context.
you can attach any view after you set the content.

So you can change

```
// compile time
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

in this

```
Button b;
```

and you can change your onCreate like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // now you can attach the view
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```

after this you can set your click listener in anonymous type like you did in next line or can still declare your listener in compile time and change this :

```
b.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class)); }

});
```

in this:

```
View.OnClickListener myClickListener = new  View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class)); 
    }
};
```

but now you need to set your OnClickListener, so your onCreate will:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // now you can attach the view
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.SetOnClickListener(myClickListener);
}
```

Hope this help to understand.